# I put a home button that put me in the beginning of the app but the background music is playing multiple times in main activity

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I put a "**home**" button in my play activity but when I click the home button it goes back to the home menu but the background music is repeating (its playing background music again in same time so it ended up playing same music everytime i click the "home" button).

Comment: You say you want a button that sends you home, but you also say you already have one. Please add your code so we can help, and explain why there is music playing. Is that the purpose of the app? Do you want music to play or not?

Comment: I have 4 activity. **w**,** x** ,**y** ,**z**/. **W** is my first activity having a background music and **Z** is my play activity. I have a home button in Z activity that open the **W** activity. But when I click the home button, it opens the **W** activity starting the background music also so it ended up playing multiple music in thee same time.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment allows us to help a bit more. Now we can see that your problem is not with your home button- it is with overlaying your music.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148615/android-stop-background-music) overflow post.