# Music doesn't play again after I press home or recents button

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have an app with a button to play or pause music. Pressing the back button while playing music pauses it and opening the app again resumes the music after pressing the play button. But that doesn't work with home or recents button. The music pauses but upon reopening the app and pressing the play button doesn't play the music until a force close. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.firozkaoo2222.myapplication;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.example.firozkaoo2222.myapplication.R.raw.police;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, police);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button policeSounds = this.findViewById(R.id.police);

    policeSounds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (policeSound == null) {
                policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.police);
            }

            if (policeSound.isPlaying()) {
                policeSound.pause();
            } else {

                policeSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (policeSound != null) {
        policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.police);
        policeSound.start();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (policeSound.isPlaying())
        policeSound.pause();
}

//Back button pressed.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (policeSound.isPlaying())
        policeSound.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    policeSound.stop();
    policeSound = null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press home button the app go to the background and when you came from the background you should override the method onResume();

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //THIS IS YOUR LAST MISTAKE. IF YOU TRY TO CREATE THE OBJECT WITH THE CONTEXT AND THE RESOUERCES
    //WHEN THE ACTIVITY IS NOT CREATED YET, YOUR APP CRASH
    //private MediaPlayer policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.police);
    private MediaPlayer policeSound;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button policeSounds = this.findViewById(R.id.police);

        policeSounds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (policeSound == null) {
                    policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.police);
                }

                if (policeSound.isPlaying()) {
                    policeSound.pause();
                } else {

                    policeSound.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (policeSound != null) {
            policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.police);
            policeSound.start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (policeSound.isPlaying())
            policeSound.pause();
    }

    //Back button pressed.
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (policeSound.isPlaying())
            policeSound.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        policeSound.stop();
        policeSound = null;
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: it is gonna work because i think that the home button stop() the policesound , so you need to start() it again so that you can play() it or pause() it , but the return button doesn't actually stop() it. you might also want to check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/9161089/9504326

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response. I didn't get the expected results though. After changing the code, the music plays automatically upon opening the app(without pressing the play button). Back button works well though still the home and recents button have the same issue

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer Doesn't work either.. Still the same just the sound plays automatically on opening the app

Comment: Opening the app when? When you came from background? When you start the app the first time? I am not able to understand what is happening. I will create a project later to understand it better.

Comment: I modified the code in the answer, try it and say me something.

Comment: I'm really sorry @JuanjoBerenguer . I only changed a few lines of code and ended up getting those errors. After changing the code entirely which was suggested by you, all the things are working properly. The hme , back and recents butons are working as I expected ( play or pause works perfectly all the time). But there is just one issue, the audio plays automatically just after launching the app (without even pressing the play button). Appreciate your help :)

Comment: You need create the media player object when you click the button the first time. That solves your problem. I a glad that I could help you. Happy coding dude

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer wouldn't be possible without you.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer I get this error " lambda expression are not supported at language level 1.7" on this line  "policeSounds.setOnClickListener(v -> {"

Comment: edited. This is because i am using Java 8 and that let you use lambda to make the code more clea. I editet the answer with the classic on click listener. I let you here an article about lamda in Android:https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/java-8-for-android-cleaner-code-with-lambda-expressions--cms-29661

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer A new error pops up after changing the code. It says " Cannot resolve method 'create(anonymous android.view.View.OnCLickListener, int)' " at this line "
public void onClick(View view) {
                if (policeSound == null){
                    policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.police); //here to be specific "

Comment: Fixed. Sorry it was a typo, this was refering the View of the clicklistener instead the context of the app. Now should work

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer The build was successful but the installation says "App not installed" .Idk whats wrong here :|

Comment: I dont know Vipul. Try to uninstall the app in the phone, Clean and Rebuild and then Install

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer Thanks a lot for your time! I never knew people here at StackOverflow are so helpful !

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding!4

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer There's something wrong with code actually. I tried running the code on the emulator and the app just opens and closes. This is happening since the last change in code

Comment: Do me a favor, edit the question with your full code in the Activity. Just copy the full activity

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer Done. Have a look

Comment: It's working again hehe :D. I let you a comment in the code, it was your last mistake.

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer You the MVP! Thanks .. No more questions :)

Comment: I am glad that you finally has the media player. Happy coding dude